# JavaScript change image on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I watched a tutorial on YouTube showing me how to make a simple version of the dino-game using JavaScript. I followed that tutorial and afterwards, I decided to add some changes to the code. After changing a few aspects, this is what I have:

```js
// Start check
setTimeout(function startobstacles() {
  obstacle.classList.add("animateObstacle")
}, 3000);

// Variable definition

var character = document.getElementById('character');
var obstacle = document.getElementById('obstacle');

var score = 0
var dead = false

// Jump movement

function jump() {

  character.classList.add("animateJump");
  setTimeout(function() {
    character.classList.remove("animateJump");
  }, 500);
}

// Check if player lost

var checkDead = setInterval(function() {
var characterTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
var obstacleLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(obstacle).getPropertyValue("left"));

if (obstacleLeft < 20 && obstacleLeft > 0 && characterTop >= 130) {
  obstacle.style.animation = "none";
  obstacle.style.diaplay = "none";

  dead = true
  var check = alert("You lost! Your score was " + score + ".");
  if (typeof check == 'undefined') {
    location.reload();
    }
  }
}, 10);

// Scoring system

setInterval(function() {
  if (dead == false) {
    score += 1;

    highScore = window.localStorage.getItem('high_score');
    if (score > highScore || highScore == null) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('high_score', score);
    }

    highScore = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('high_score'));

    document.getElementById("scoreBoard").innerHTML = "Your score: " + score + " | Your personal best: " + highScore;
  }
}, 2000)
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

#scoreBoard{
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#game {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url("images/background.png");
}

#character {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 142px;
}

#obstacle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 450px;
}

.animateJump {
  animation: jump 0.5s
}

.animateObstacle {
  animation: obstacle 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes obstacle {
  0%{left: 429px;}
  100%{left: -429px;}
}

@keyframes jump {
  0%{top: 142px;}
  50%{top: 100px;}
  100%{top: 142px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Welcome to Mouse Run! In this game, your goal is to avoid touching the infected cheese. If you do, you lose! Press \"OK\" to start.")
      alert("Use LEFT CLICK to jump!")
    </script>

    <link rel="icon" href="images/thumbnail.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mouse Run</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body onclick="jump();" style="background-color: lightblue">

    <!-- Main Game -->
    <p id="title"></p>
    <div id="game">
      <div id="character"><img class="noselect" src="images/player.png"></div>
      <div id="obstacle"><img class="noselect" src="images/obstacle.png" style="height: 20px; width: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
    <p id="scoreBoard"></p>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

With all this code, I get something like this:

[image: example]

So right now, the character can only jump. I want to give it the ability to dash. My plan was to make a second image for the mouse and swap between that image when the user presses a certain key to dash. The problem is that I don't really know how to swap images in this situation.

So does anyone know how to do this? If you might, please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: character.src = "path/to/new/image.gif";

Comment: There is a button that looks liek this: `<>`. You can use that to share your HTML, CSS and JS in a way that we can run it and easily paste it into our answers.

Comment: espascerello I tried and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Basically, put `character.src = "images/thumbnail.png"` in the jump function. I suppose that if it works, it would change the mouse image to the thumbnail image (which are different) when I left click. But instead, nothing really happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oh it is because character is the parent, not the image.... so select the image and set the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually dont need the `img` tag under `character div`. You can set the `background-image` of the character div. And change the background-image on `.animateJump` style.

See the Snippet below:

```js
// Start check
setTimeout(function startobstacles() {
  obstacle.classList.add("animateObstacle")
}, 3000);

// Variable definition

var character = document.getElementById('character');
var obstacle = document.getElementById('obstacle');

var score = 0
var dead = false

// Jump movement

function jump() {
  character.classList.add("animateJump");
  setTimeout(function() {
    character.classList.remove("animateJump");
  }, 500);
}

// Check if player lost

var checkDead = setInterval(function() {
var characterTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
var obstacleLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(obstacle).getPropertyValue("left"));

if (obstacleLeft < 20 && obstacleLeft > 0 && characterTop >= 130) {
  obstacle.style.animation = "none";
  obstacle.style.diaplay = "none";

  dead = true
  //var check = alert("You lost! Your score was " + score + ".");
  if (typeof check == 'undefined') {
    location.reload();
    }
  }
}, 10);

// Scoring system

setInterval(function() {
  if (dead == false) {
    score += 1;

    highScore = window.localStorage.getItem('high_score');
    if (score > highScore || highScore == null) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('high_score', score);
    }

    highScore = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('high_score'));

    document.getElementById("scoreBoard").innerHTML = "Your score: " + score + " | Your personal best: " + highScore;
  }
}, 2000)
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

#scoreBoard{
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#game {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gZSc.png");
    background-size: 107%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#character {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 142px;
}

#character{
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr7LnFBd0jsRiAUQ7jqerEKt1CujA3yFJFQA&usqp=CAU");
  width: 20px;
  
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#obstacle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 450px;
}

#character.animateJump {
  animation: jump 0.5s;
  background-image: url("https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180616/vvf/kisspng-disco-dance-silhouette-clip-art-bailando-5b2586082d6d97.6157716515291858001861.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}

.animateObstacle {
  animation: obstacle 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes obstacle {
  0%{left: 429px;}
  100%{left: -429px;}
}

@keyframes jump {
  0%{top: 142px;}
  50%{top: 100px;}
  100%{top: 142px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //alert("Welcome to Mouse Run! In this game, your goal is to avoid touching the infected cheese. If you do, you lose! Press \"OK\" to start.")
      //alert("Use LEFT CLICK to jump!")
    </script>

    <link rel="icon" href="images/thumbnail.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mouse Run</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body onclick="jump();" style="background-color: lightblue">

    <!-- Main Game -->
    <p id="title"></p>
    <div id="game">
      <div id="character"></div>
      <div id="obstacle"><img class="noselect" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHR5g.png" style="height: 20px;"></div>
    </div>
    <p id="scoreBoard"></p>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Look for the comment "Added below lines" and "Added above lines"

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/wagvq8kz/8/) also.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I tried your example and everything worked well. But when I tried implementing it into my code, the images became very small and sometimes not even visible.

Comment: you can change the size of image. `width: 20px;` in #character style,

Answer (score 2):

Changing the src of the image should work.

```
function jump() {
  let characterImage = character.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[0];
  characterImage.src = "images/player_dash.png"; // Path to the new image (change it to the actual name)
  setTimeout(function() {
      characterImage.src = "images/player.png";
  }, 500);
}
```